# Edit data using ListBox in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu, listbox

I am currently using the ListView grid format to display data from the db using a SqlDataSource. Is there a way when I click edit that only that specific row becomes a listbox
and each column becomes editable, all other rows stays the same.

For example,

```
Row1
    Col1 Edit(Maybe using a dropdown)
    Col2 Edit
    Col3 Edit
Row 2    Col1      Col2    Col3
Row 3    Col1      Col2    Col3
```

Here is my code thus far:(This edits everything using a dropdownlist for each field)

```
        <EditItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #999999;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="overflow:auto; width:300px;">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="formtitle" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="FormTitle" DataValueField="FormTitle" Width="300px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("FormTitle") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="overflow:auto; width:300px;">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="formsection" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="FormSection" DataValueField="FormSection" Width="300px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("FormSection") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="overflow:auto; width:300px;">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="subsection" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="SubSection" DataValueField="SubSection" Width="300px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("SubSection") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                </div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="SubSectionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SubSection") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="overflow:auto; width:300px;">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="sectionitem" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="SectionItem" DataValueField="SectionItem" Width="300px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("SectionItem") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                </div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="SectionItemTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SectionItem") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Do you mean like the entire edit row becomes just one ListBox or instead of multiple DropDownLists, have multiple ListBoxes?

Comment: @BubbleHearth The entire row becomes a listbox, and each field have a dropdownlist so I can edit it.

Comment: So you want the ListBox to contain different fields of DropDownLists? If so, I think you may be misunderstanding what a ListBox does. A ListBox is essentially a DropDownList without the drop-down part that allows multiple selections if you need it.

Comment: @BubbleHearth Hmm ok. So is there a way to pick a specific column in a row that I want to edit and only make a listbox out of that particular column?

Comment: Out of the box, a ListView only lets you edit the entire row. You won't be able to just edit one column at a time. If you really needed to, I'm sure you could build a way to basically "fake" that kind of functionality though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a `ListBox` in the edit row, just replace whatever `DropDownList` you want with a `ListBox`. A `ListBox` will instead show all of the items without the drop-down functionality and it will also allow for multiple selections. It is not however, used as a container for other controls. For example:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listbox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="FormTitle" DataValueField="FormTitle"></asp:ListBox>
```

After clearing up a few things, it sounds like you may want to check out [this article titled: In-place editing of ListView subitems.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6646/In-place-editing-of-ListView-subitems) Out of the box, a ListView only allows the editing of an entire row at once, not individual cells. The article I linked explains how that could be done.